# Google maps is not being rendered in a page that is being loaded using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-maps

I am trying to `load (append) a php script by name child.php to a parent.php file via ajax` call.

```
$.get("child.php", function(data) {
   $("div-for-child").append(data);
}
```

The child.php contain script to load google maps. But this is not happening.

```
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        initialise(cordinates, id, paramas);
    };
</script>
```

And the `initialise` function is:

```
function initialise() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(cordinates); 
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8, 
            minZoom: 6, 
            maxZoom: 17, 
            zoomControl:true, 
            zoomControlOptions: {
                style:google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.DEFAULT 
            },
            center: myLatlng, 
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 
            panControl:false, // Set to false to disable
            mapTypeControl:false, // Disable Map/Satellite switch
            scaleControl:false, // Set to false to hide scale
            streetViewControl:false, // Set to disable to hide street view
            overviewMapControl:false, // Set to false to remove overview control
            rotateControl:false // Set to false to disable rotate control
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

        var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage("image/path", null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(40,52)); 


        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ // Set the marker
            position: myLatlng, // Position marker to coordinates
            icon:image, //use our image as the marker
            map: map, // assign the market to our map variable
            title: 'Click to visit our company on Google Places'    });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ // Create a new InfoWindow
            content:"<h3>Snowdown Summit Cafe</h3><p>Railway Drive-through available.</p>" // HTML contents of the InfoWindow
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { // Add a Click Listener to our marker
            infowindow.open(map,marker); // Open our InfoWindow
        });

    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialise); // Execute our 'initialise' function once the page has loaded. 

The initalise function is an external script.
```

So the final picture. Whenever I `load or append child.php to parent.php via ajax`. The map in `child.php` is not being loaded. I just get an empty `div` with no content.

The head section is:

```
<head>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"> </script>
<script src="js/map.js"> // Initialise function is here in map.js file
</head>
```

Comment: Are you trying in offline? Can you share your head section?

Comment: I will upload the code for head section. No I am not trying this offline.

Comment: Possible [pointer](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html#Loading_the_Maps_API) for you.